# Providing callback in a _.forEach construct

Tags: javascript, postman

(Working in the Postman environment) it was detected that the following code runs through all the url requests without printing the result.

```
    _.forEach(
            urls,
            function (myUrl) {            
                pm.sendRequest({
                    url: myUrl,
                    method: 'GET',
                    header: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json'                    
                    }
                }, function (err, res) {
                    console.log(res)
                });            
            }
        )
        pm.environment.set(`sections`,sections);
    }
```

Is there any way to provide a callback within forEach, might appear something like given below code. Or is there any alternative to it.

```
    function callback() {
        console.log('callback');
    }

    _.forEach(
            urls,
            function (myUrl,callback) {            
                pm.sendRequest({
                    url: myUrl,
                    method: 'GET',
                    header: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json'                    
                    }
                }, function (err, res) {
                    console.log(res)
                });            
            }
        )
        pm.environment.set(`sections`,sections);
    }
```

I had initially thought that the response handling function at the end would take care of that but it doesn't.

Comment: You don't need to try and pass `callback` as an argument, it is already in scope so you can simply call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it better to branch out the logic into another function getUrl and pass the callback into it.

Following code works:

```
_.forEach (
    urls,
    function (myUrl) {
        getUrl(myUrl,function (err,res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
            }
        });
    }
);

function getUrl(myUrl, callback) {
    var call = {
        url: myUrl,
        method: 'GET',
        header: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    pm.sendRequest(
        call,
        function (err, res) {
            callback (err,res);
        }
    );
}
```